# Docker swarm task state Failed VS Rejected

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

According to docs, when a task fails to starts, then a new one is created and tries to move to the Running state. I also confirmed this behavior.

What happens when a task is rejected? I saw that when it was rejected, no new task is being created, and the stack which the task belongs to remains in this state forever.

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 5):

When the task is rejected, it tries again in a different/same node, but until you resolve the reason for the rejection, it will just shop around trying to find  a node in which all requirements can be fulfilled.

You can check what went wrong with:

```
docker service ps --no-trunc <service>
```

And/or

```
docker inspect <task id>
```

Please note:

> "the --no-trunc was added in docker 1.13; for docker 1.12, use the docker inspect approach" https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26004